# What overall measure/analysis to use for a collection of correlation coefficients?

Tags: correlation, inference, spearman-rho

in my research I am looking at concordance of epileptic attacks using the EEG-signal from the attacks. For every patient (25) a x number of attacks (ranging between 5 and 50) is recorded. For every recording lead, for every frequency band (delta, theta, alpha, beta etc.) an excitation score is calculated. Using these scores, correlation coefficients (Spearman rho) are calculated for every pair of epileptic attacks, resulting in a matrix of correlation coefficients for each subject.

Now my question is, *what would be a suitable and statistically correct way to get one number for the 'overall' correlation between the attacks of a patient, based on the matrix of correlation coefficients (rho's) of the attacks that I have?*

I have read about Fisher Z transformations to 'average' the coefficients (which I understood to be less suitable for Spearman rho's compared with Pearson r's). However, if this is indeed a suitable approach for the problem above, what would be the correct approach for statistical inference/calculating confidence intervals?

Comment: Any method for pooling correlations is inferior to pooling the data and re-doing the analysis. But with nothing else to hand but the correlations, Fisher $z$ often works well -- perhaps more by making the distribution more symmetrical (often) than by anything else. I am not aware of any distinction between Spearman and Pearson here: Spearman correlations _are_ Pearson correlations, fed the ranks not the original data, but I would welcome precise references or detailed arguments on that point.

Comment: Picky point on notation: I would suggest that convention and statistical logic are better served by $r$ for Pearson correlation, $r_S$ for Spearman correlation as calculated from data and $\rho, \rho_S$ for what is being estimated. That way, $\rho$ (rho) is used for the parameter concerned. But there is no notation without a downside. Small essays could be written on the misuse of $=$ and $+$.

Comment: I disagree with the tag wiki for `spearman-rho`. Whether Spearman correlation is "usually" denoted rho is hard for me to judge overall, but that isn't the case in literature I see. And defining it as a measure of concordance is not much use without a definition of concordance. $y$ and a trillion times that have Spearman correlation of 1, but are they concordant?

Comment: Nick, thank you for your answer. I agree with your remark that any method would be inferior to pooling, so that is what I am going to try! The distinction in this context between Spearman/Pearson was based on a comment I read [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_calculate_the_average_correlation_across_samples_in_a_meta_analysis): _I would avoid the r-to-z transformation, it is known to inflate **rho**, introducing bias into the estimate_. But not sure if I interpreted that right.

Comment: That comment in turn leads to a reference I can't access. On the face of it, the assertion is nonsensical: $r$ to $z$ leaves $r$ unchanged. Whether working with $z$ and back-transforming to the $r$ scale does the right thing depends on the details. There is no white magic and how to summarize several correlations if one or more are very different is a tricky question -- especially if various samples have quite different sizes, which seems all too frequent here. A typical application is meta-analysis when papers give correlations and possibly sample sizes but little or nothing else.